# Calculations on Geodesic Grid & Plotting Data of Geodesic Grid - any C Librarys availible?

Tags: c, plot, grid, geometry

I have a couple of questions regarding computations in C on a geodesic grid.
I want to numerically solve equations for the time evolution of a scalar field on the surface of a sphere.
It seems that the geodesic grid is a convenient way to parametrize the surface of the sphere and to store it in the computers memory.
An explanation on one possible data structure is given here:
http://kiwi.atmos.colostate.edu/BUGS/geodesic/text.html

I would like to know:

Are there any C Libraries available which I can use to simplify my life, or should I create the data structure myself?
Having a data structure such as the one presented in the link above, are there any programs to visualize functions that are defined on the grid? (I want to plot some computed value for every grid point, but visualized on the sphere).
For this would it be best to write on code that assigns every grid point a set of angles (theta, phi) and then plot with e.g gnuplot?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.